# Scrapy SitemapSpider not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl the website of a prominent UK retailer and get an attributeError as follows:

> nl_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/sitemap.py", line 52, in _parse_sitemap
>       for r, c in self._cbs:
>
> AttributeError: 'NlSMCrawlerSpider' object has no attribute '_cbs'

It's probably me not fully conceiving how a SitemapSpider operates - see my code below:

```
class NlSMCrawlerSpider(SitemapSpider):
name = 'nl_smcrawler'
allowed_domains = ['newlook.com']
sitemap_urls = ['http://www.newlook.com/uk/sitemap/maps/sitemap_uk_product_en_1.xml']
sitemap_follow = ['/uk/womens/clothing/']

# sitemap_rules = [
#     ('/uk/womens/clothing/', 'parse_product'),
# ]


def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
    self.driver.set_window_size(800,600)
    time.sleep(2)


def parse_product(self, response):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(1)

    # Collect products
    itemDetails = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product-details-page content')


    # Pull features
    desc = itemDetails[0].find_element_by_class_name('product-description__name').text
    href = driver.current_url

    # Generate a product identifier
    identifier = href.split('/p/')[1].split('?comp')[0]
    identifier = int(identifier)

    # datetime
    dt = date.today()
    dt = dt.isoformat()

    # Price Symbol removal and integer conversion
    try:
        priceString = itemDetails[0].find_element_by_class_name('price product-description__price').text
    except:
        priceString = itemDetails[0].find_element_by_class_name('price--previous-price product-description__price--previous-price ng-scope').text
    priceInt = priceString.split('£')[1]
    originalPrice = float(priceInt)

    # discountedPrice Logic
    try:
        discountedPriceString = itemDetails[0].find_element_by_class_name('price price--marked-down product-description__price').text
        discountedPriceInt = discountedPriceString.split('£')[1]
        discountedPrice = float(discountedPriceInt)
    except:
        discountedPrice = 'N/A'

    # NlScrapeItem
    item = NlScrapeItem()

    # Append product to NlScrapeItem
    item['identifier'] = identifier
    item['href'] = href
    item['description'] = desc
    item['originalPrice'] = originalPrice
    item['discountedPrice'] = discountedPrice
    item['firstSighted'] = dt
    item['lastSighted'] = dt

    yield item
```

Also, don't hesitate to ask for any further details, see the link to the [sitemap](http://www.newlook.com/uk/sitemap/maps/sitemap_uk_product_en_1.xml) and a link to the actual file within the Scrapy package throwing off the error ([link - github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/sitemap.py)). Your help would be sincerely appreciated.

Edit: One Thought
looking at the [2nd link](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/sitemap.py) (from the Scrapy package), I can see _cbs is initialised in the `def __init__(self, *a, **kw):` function - is the fact that I have my own **init** logic throwing it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issue are there in your scraper. One is the `__init__` method

```
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
    self.driver.set_window_size(800, 600)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Now you have defined a new `__init__` and overridden the base class `__init__`. Which is not called by your init and hence the `_cbs` is not initialized. You can easily fix this by changing your init method as below

```
def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
    super(NlSMCrawlerSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)

    self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
    self.driver.set_window_size(800, 600)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Next the SitemapScraper will always send response to the parse method. And you have not defined the parse method at all. So I added a simple one to just print the urls

```
def parse(self, response):
    print(response.url)
```